# jQuery validate plugin displays [object Object] when I try to output a custom errorPlacement

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I'm using this code to move the placement of errors:

```
$("#passengerdetailsform").validate({errorPlacement: errorPlacement});

function errorPlacement(error, element)
{
    $('#error').append(error + '<br />');
}
```

I add the class="required" to the fields that I want to be present when the form is submitted.

The #error div is populated with "[object Object]" and I can't find the documentation for the properties of this object to get out the message.

How can I modify my code so that it will correctly display the error message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `error` parameter passed to your function is a `label` HTML element (or whatever element you specified in the `errorElement` parameter), wrapped in a jQuery object. This is why you see `[object Object]`. To make it appear correctly on your page try this:

```
function errorPlacement(error, element) {
    error.appendTo("#error");
}
```

[Further information](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#errorplacement)

Comment: Perfect - thank you - I even tried enumerating the object to no avail